# hasRole() in spring security does not work properly

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

I try to do roles in my application. But I have a message all the time.

> ```
>     "status": 403,
>     "error": "Forbidden",
>     "message": "Forbidden",
> ```

In database I have column role and values USER or ADMIN

> RestController

```
@GetMapping(value="/users")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE ADMIN')")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllusers(){
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println(authentication.getAuthorities());
    List<User> users = userService.findAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

if I comments `@PreAuthorize` `System.out.println(authentication.getAuthorities());` shows `"ROLE ADMIN"` or `"ROLE USER"` correctly

Comment: You don't have `ROLE_USER` but `USER` as the role. The `hasRole` checks the given authority but will prefix it with `ROLE_` use `hasAuthority` instead.

Comment: I tried with @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") and @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") and all the time error 403

Comment: As stated `hasRole` prefixes the passed in authority with `ROLE_` leading to check if you user has the authority `ROLE_ADMIN` which it doesn't have because it is named `ADMIN`. Use `hasAuthority` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're creating the authorities in wrong way , authorities should prefix DB role with the `ROLE_` in your case , it would be `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_USER` (you missed the underscore )

So , your `UserDetails`'s `getAuthorities()` implementation should fill role in proper manner like :

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();

    /* this is just a sample , you must implement bringing data from repository then prefix every string with ROLE_ */
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

    return authorities;
}
```

then in your controller, `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` should work, (remove `ROLE_`) , 
also you can use `hasAuthority(‘ROLE_ADMIN’),`

Comment: This works, permission name should be proper.`@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE ADMIN')")`